# Substituting images for mobile viewing

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

I have images on my website which I need relatively hi-res for desktop however when i am viewing these images on my mobile, the images are too big and dont load.
The images are about 140kb per image. I have a lower res version for mobile.
How do I set a rules for swapping out an image for a mobile device?

Current CSS:

```
.staff-1{
    background:url("../matt_about_HR.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 4px 4px 10px 0px;
}
.staff-2{
    background:url("../about_shail_photo_HR.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 4px 4px 10px 0px;
}
.staff-3{
    background:url("../about_Leah_photo.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 4px 4px 10px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS3 @media Rule, this will provide you style rules for different media types/devices depending on the width and height of the browser window. Please see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. This should also work with background images.

Comment: Does this mean that the previous image loads in the background or is it set as "Display:none"?

Comment: The previous CSS setting will be ignored and will use the new rule as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are one way and are frequently used for this. If you're using Bootstrap CSS you can just use the hidden-xs, visible-xs etc. classes to swap the images depending on the device sizes. I've used it before to serve completely different layouts and images based on device sizes.

You can also add retina.js to show better quality (bigger file size) images only on devices that have retina displays. While not directly related to your question I find it useful and means it doesn't serve the @2x (double file size) images to devices on which they will have no benefit.